# let's encrypt SSL ceritificate reissue (certbot) in aws autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, autoscaling, certbot

I am using let's encrypt in amazon ec2. This will be part of an autoscaling group. The lets encrypt certificates expire every 90 days and has an auto reissue through IP domain IP/A value check. How does this work with multiple IPs? Since individual instances will have different IPs, won't this result in certificate reissue failure?

Comment: Do you need each instance to have its own cert?  Or can you have a load balancer in front of them with an AWS ACM cert on it?

Comment: The issue is first end to end encryption. But more importantly I am facing an issue with http connection. No response from server. So, this is my only option for now.

Comment: For end to end encryption on an ELB, the instance doesn't need to have a valid cert for the domain, you can generate a self signed cert locally on the instance.  Is the HTTP connection issue when going directly to the instance, or only when going through an ELB?  Try doing a curl -Ikv (thats a capital i, not lowercase L) to the IP and see if its generating an error, or just timing out.  Might be a security group/NACL/routing issue